# Using Mathematica to create an H-Tree

Tags: plotting, fractals

Can folks show me several methods I can use to draw the following fractal H-Tree?

[image]

I did use Free-Form input, as:

```
= h-fractal
```

And got this image, which is three iterations, but no idea how it was formed.

[image]

Comment: Make an H.  Then place the center of four 1/10 size Hs on the tips of each leg.  Iterate.

Comment: See the demonstration ["H-Fractal"](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HFractal/) and [`SubstitutionSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html).

Answer (score 13):

**Iterative version**

Each horisontal line generates two vertical lines of the same length,
while each vertical line generates two horisontal lines, which are twice shorter:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[Line[{a_,b_}]]:=With[{d=Reverse@Abs[a-b]/{2,4}},{Line@{a+d,a-d},Line@{b+d,b-d}}];
Graphics[NestList[f, Line[{{-1,0},{1,0}}], 10], AspectRatio->1]
```

[image: H-Fractal]

**Simple version**

Draw an H-shaped figure in every point of a rectangular grid. Repeat with finer grid spacing.

```
drawH[size_][{x_,y_}]:={
    Line[{{x,y}+{-size,0},{x,y}+{size,0}}],
    Line[{{x,y}+{-size,size},{x,y}+{-size,-size}}],
    Line[{{x,y}+{size,size},{x,y}+{size,-size}}]
    };

drawAllH[size_]:= Map[drawH[size], 
    CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-2,2},{-2,2}}, 4 size, Center], {2}];

Graphics[Map[drawAllH, 1/2^(Range[4]-1)]]
```

[image: Larger H-Fractal]

Comment: Your iterative example (first example) gave me this error: `SetDelayed::write: Tag Plus in (5-3 x-2 x^2+x^3)[Line[{a_,b_}]] is Protected.`. I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.

Comment: @David You have defined `f` somewhere earlier. Try `ClearAll[f]`

Comment: Perfect. You were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple-minded implementation based on repeated scaling:

```
With[{n = 6, s = 1./3}, 
     Graphics[Flatten[NestList[# /. Line[{p1_, p2_}] :> 
                               Map[Line,
                                   Outer[Plus, {p1, p2},
                                         Outer[Times, {-1, 1}, s Cross[p2 - p1]], 1]] &,
                               Line[{{-0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.}}], 2 n - 1]]]]
```

[image: h-tree]

Answer (score 8):

define a function `drawH`

```
drawH[{x_, y_}, size_] := 
 Line[{{{x + size, y}, {x - size, y}}, {{x + size, 
     y + size}, {x + size, y - size}}, {{x - size, 
     y + size}, {x - size, y - size}}}]
```

Then use `NestList` to iteration

```
size = 1;
Graphics[NestList[(size = size*.5;Level[#[[All, 1, 2 ;;]], {-2}, 
     drawH[#, size] & /@ {##} &]) &, {drawH[{0, 0}, 1]}, 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Faster version

```
n = 3;
s = 1;
{a, b, c, d} = {{-1, -s}, {-1, s}, {1, -s}, {1, s}};
m = {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}/2, #} & /@ {a, b, c, d};
L = Line[{{a, b}, {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {c, d}}];
Graphics[NestList[GeometricTransformation[#, m] &, L, n]]
```

[image]